# How to make product diapason pagination in OpenCart 2.x?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have OpenCart 2.1 and the website has such pagination (see screenshot)
[default pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFnCD.png)

Here is the question: How to make like a product diapason pagination in OpenCart?

When I say the diapason pagination, I mean this (see screenshot please)

[diapason pagination screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quqGD.jpg)

Here is some code that is responsible for the formation of pagination.

```
<?php
class Pagination {
    public $total = 0;
    public $page = 1;
    public $limit = 20;
    public $num_links = 8;
    public $url = '';
    public $text_first = '|&lt;';
    public $text_last = '&gt;|';
    public $text_next = '&gt;';
    public $text_prev = '&lt;';
public function render() {
    $total = $this->total;

    if ($this->page < 1) {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $page = $this->page;
    }

    if (!(int)$this->limit) {
        $limit = 10;
    } else {
        $limit = $this->limit;
    }

    $num_links = $this->num_links;
    $num_pages = ceil($total / $limit);

    $this->url = str_replace('%7Bpage%7D', '{page}', $this->url);

    $output = '<ul class="pagination">';

    if ($page > 1) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', 1, $this->url) . '">' . $this->text_first . '</a></li>';
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $page - 1, $this->url) . '">' . $this->text_prev . '</a></li>';
    }

    if ($num_pages > 1) {
        if ($num_pages <= $num_links) {
            $start = 1;
            $end = $num_pages;
        } else {
            $start = $page - floor($num_links / 2);
            $end = $page + floor($num_links / 2);

            if ($start < 1) {
                $end += abs($start) + 1;
                $start = 1;
            }

            if ($end > $num_pages) {
                $start -= ($end - $num_pages);
                $end = $num_pages;
            }
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
            if ($page == $i) {
                $output .= '<li class="active"><span>' . $i . '</span></li>';
            } else {
                $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($page < $num_pages) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $page + 1, $this->url) . '">' . $this->text_next . '</a></li>';
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $num_pages, $this->url) . '">' . $this->text_last . '</a></li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';

    if ($num_pages > 1) {
        return $output;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: replace $I in output with ($i-1) . ' - ' . ($i * $this->limit)

Comment: thank you. But it looks like this https://imgur.com/a/cKWNh you can see number of page and how many products. How to make diapason? For example on the first page 1-18 on the second page 18-36 and so on

Comment: ($i-1) * $this->limit . ' - ' . ($i * $this->limit)